# Norm of the Resolvent of a Self-Adjoint Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, self-learning, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal L$ is a self- adjoint operator with a discrete spectrum $\{\lambda_{j}\}$.

I read that it is well known that for, $\lambda \notin \sigma(\mathcal L)$,

$$\left|(L- \lambda I)^{-1}\right| \leq \sup_{j}\frac{1}{|\lambda - \lambda_{j}|}.$$

How to show this well-known result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That follows from the continuous functional calculus of self adjoint operator. Which states that there is an isometric homomorphism

$$\Phi: C(\sigma(\mathcal L)) \to B(\mathcal H)$$

from the space of continuous functions on $\sigma(\mathcal L)$ to $B(H)$, given by $\Phi(f) = f(\mathcal L)$ which extends the map $p(x) \mapsto p(\mathcal L)$ on polynomails. Now if $\lambda \notin \sigma(\mathcal L)$, then $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-\lambda}$ is continuous on $\sigma(\mathcal L)$. As

$$I= \Phi (1) = \Phi \bigg((x-\lambda) \frac{1}{x-\lambda} \bigg) = (\mathcal L-\lambda I) f(\mathcal L), $$
We see that $f(\mathcal L) = (\mathcal L - \lambda I)^{-1}$ and thus

$$||(\mathcal L - \lambda I)^{-1} || = ||f||_0 = \sup_j \frac{1}{|\lambda - \lambda_j|}$$

So actually we have equality.

Comment: Does this result hold for general spectrum instead of discrete one, please?

Comment: It does. As long as $\mathcal L$ is bounded self adjoint.

Comment: It holds for unbounded selfadjoint operators, too. The sup in either case can be taken over the spectrum; the type or cardinality of spectrum does not matter.

Comment: I do not get the last part of your proof. $||(\mathcal L - \lambda I)^{-1} || = ||f||_0 = \sup_j \frac{1}{|\lambda - \lambda_j|}$. Do you mean infinity norm instead of $0$ norm? If so, why? Also why the infinity norm is the sup thing?

Comment: Yes, I mean the sup norm: $||f||_0 = \sup_{x\in \sigma(\mathcal L)} |f(x)|$. In this case, $||1/(x-\lambda)||_0= \sup_j 1/|\lambda_j  -\lambda|$.

Comment: I think infinity norm due to isometry, theorem is called Gelfand-Naimark theorem and it is a special case for self-adjoint operator